# Calibrating the Shutter Speed/ISO Dial on Film Camera?

Tags: film, repair, 35mm, film-cameras, repair-parts

The camera is a Bell & Howell Auto 35 Reflex (Model 237), aka the Canon EXEE.

How does one calibrate/set the position of this shutter speed + ASA dial (lifting the dial's outer ring adjusts the ASA), having been removed without recording its original position(s)? It looks to me like the gear on the left is part of some sort of rotary contact encoder but I have no clue which contact it should be touching when I put the dial back in. I believe it measures the position of the dial for the "EE" aperture setting, so that EE can calculate exposure correctly and do its job?

Secondly, is this "calibration" required even if I don't plan on using any electronic auto modes? It looks like the wire, which should be soldered to the left edge of the silicon plate, has broken off, making this encoder useless. I could easily solder it back on but not sure if it's worth my time.

Thanks!
[image]